# REST API design for collection that is naturally divided into subcollections

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, rest, api-design

I have a a collection of requests send from my client application to server that handles them. I create new request with this request

```
POST api/v1/requests
```

After the request is send it recieves the status `PENDING` and after being evaluated the staus is changed to `RESOLVED`. Thus I have collection `requests` that is divided into 2 subcollections: `requests.pending` and `requests.resolved`. **I need a way to get pagable access to both of them AND to be albe to cache those pages.**

**Would it be the REST way to make them like this**:

```
GET api/v1/requests/page/:page            - returns pages of all requests collection
GET api/v1/requests/pending/page/:page    - returns pages of pending requests collection
GET api/v1/requests/resolved/page/:page   - returns pages of resolved requests collection
```

I'm a bit uncomfortable with this approach as main **resource** is `requests` collection and I'm creating 2 artificial collection (or stores) on top of it. Nevertheless I think I can't just approach this with query params like this as query parameters are not supposed to be cached witin REST protocol by cache servers:

```
GET api/v1/requests/?page=:page            - returns pages of all requests
```

Comment: updated the title.

Comment: Github has something like this as described here: https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/#list-public-events-that-a-user-has-received

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a **LOT** of ways to do your urls here and I'm sure there will be several (**strong**) opinions given.

My recommendation would be the following...

```
POST ../api/v1/request
```

The v1 vs 1 is my personal preference, I think the v1 is more descriptive than just a 1.

There are a lot of discussions of plural vs singular for resource names.  My preference is for singular.

```
// redirects to a paginated url
GET ../api/v1/request -> ../api/v1/request?page=1&rpp=10

// your default page that return all types of requests ordered
// however you want, most likely reverse date created.
GET ../api/v1/request?page=1&rpp=10

// returns pending requests.
GET ../api/v1/request?page=1&rpp=10&status=pending

// returns resolved requests.
GET ../api/v1/request?page=1&rpp=10&status=resolved
```

Here is my thinking...  From what I can tell, you're actually trying to query the requests that you have.

Generally, more specific/nested urls are for child relationships.

For example, get all the addresses for a specific customer:

```
GET ../api/v1/customer/1/address
```

All the above urls would be able to be cacheable and bookmarkable.

Comment: one of the archetypes of REST is `controller` that basically sasys that you crete some action on the selected resources, thus additional level of nesting could represent the action on some reource, based on previous parts of URI, so why I shouldn't put `/pending` at the end of URI to select pending requests?

Comment: You can.  Like I said there are lots of ways to slice and dice "RESTful" urls.  But, what I feel that you're really trying to do is find requests with the status of pending.  So maybe `../api/v1/request/status/pending`.  It still feels like you're trying to query the request resource though.  But, there are many ways of doing what you're trying to do and the way you want to do it most likely would work fine.  Are you concerned about the code in the Controller and having to do `if` statements in your controller?  Because there are ways around that if needed.